# How to binary search for a specific year in an array of objects containing a specific year

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

I'm trying to get the code to search for a songs that were made in a specific year

I've tried implementing my own binary search code but it's not working and instead asks for an input when I never asked for an input

Class:

```
public class MusicV3
{
// instance variables
private int year;
private String title;
private String artist;

// Constructor for objects of class Music
public MusicV3(String t, int y, String a)
{
    // initialize instance variables
    title = t;
    year = y;
    artist = a;
}

public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String t)
{
    title = t;
}

public String getArtist()
{
    return artist;
}

public void setArtist(String a)
{
    artist = a;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public void setTitle(int y)
{
    year = y;
}

public String toString()
{
    String str = String.format( "%-25s %4d   %-20s ", title,  year , artist);
    return str;
}
```

}

Tester class:

```
     public class MusicV3Tester
     {
      public static void main(String[]args)
     {
    int find = 0;
    MusicV3[] songs = new MusicV3[10];
    MusicV3[] sortedSongs = new MusicV3[songs.length];
    songs[0] = new MusicV3("Sugar", 2014, "Maroon 5");
    songs[1] = new MusicV3("Mercy", 2016, "Shawn Mendes");
    songs[2] = new MusicV3("Shape of You", 2017, "Ed Sheeran");
    songs[3] = new MusicV3("Photograph", 2014, "Ed Sheeran");
    songs[4] = new MusicV3("Closer", 2016, "The Chainsmokers");
    songs[5] = new MusicV3("Galway Girl", 2017, "Ed Sheeran");
    songs[6] = new MusicV3("Counting Stars", 2013, "OneRepublic");
    songs[7] = new MusicV3("7 Years", 2015, "Lukas Graham");
    songs[8] = new MusicV3("Night Changes", 2014, "One Direction");
    songs[9] = new MusicV3("What Makes You Beautiful", 2011, "One Direction");

    printSongs(songs);
    System.out.println();

    sortedSongs = sortBySong(songs);
    System.out.println("Song list sorted by songs:");
    //printSongs(sortedSongs);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching for the song: Paris");
    find = findSong(songs, "Paris");
    if(find != -1){
        System.out.println("We found Paris in the song list: ");
        System.out.println(sortedSongs[find]);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Paris is not in the song list");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching for the song: Sugar");
    find = findSong(songs, "Sugar");
    if(find != -1){
        System.out.println("We found Sugar in the song list: ");
        System.out.println(sortedSongs[find]);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Sugar is not in the song list");
    System.out.println();

    sortedSongs = sortByYear(songs);
    System.out.println("Song list sorted by year:");
    //printSongs(sortedSongs);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching for the year: 2000");
    find = findYear(songs, 2000);
    if(find != -1){
        System.out.println("We found songs made in the year 2000 in the song list: ");
        System.out.println(sortedSongs[find]);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Songs made in the year 2000 are not in the song list");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching for the year: 2014");
    findYear(songs, 2014);
    if(find != -1){
        System.out.println("We found songs made in the year 2014 in the song list: ");
        System.out.println(sortedSongs[find]);
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Songs made in the year 2014 are not in the song list");
    System.out.println();

    sortedSongs = sortByArtist(songs);
    System.out.println("Song list sorted by artist:");
    //printSongs(sortedSongs);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching for the artist: Sia");
    findArtist(songs, "Sia");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Searching for the artist: Ed Sheeran");
    findArtist(songs, "Ed Sheeran");
    System.out.println();
}

public static void printSongs(MusicV3[] s)
{
    System.out.println("Song                      Year   Artist");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
        System.out.println(s[i]);
}

public static MusicV3[] sortBySong(MusicV3 [] songs){
    MusicV3[] sortedList = songs;
    int i;
    int k;
    int posmax;
    MusicV3 temp;
    for ( i = songs.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
    {
       posmax = 0;
         for ( k = 0 ; k <= i ; k++ )
         {
             if (songs[k].getTitle().compareTo(songs[posmax].getTitle()) > 0)
             posmax = k;
            }

            temp = songs[i];
            songs[i] = songs[posmax];
            songs[posmax] = temp;
        }
return sortedList;
}

public static MusicV3[] sortByYear(MusicV3 [] movies){
    MusicV3[] sortedList = movies;
    int i;
    int k;
    int posmax;
    MusicV3 temp;
    for ( i = movies.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
    {
       posmax = 0;
         for ( k = 0 ; k <= i ; k++ )
         {
             if (movies[k].getYear()> movies[posmax].getYear())
             posmax = k;
            }

            temp = movies[i];
            movies[i] = movies[posmax];
            movies[posmax] = temp;
}
return sortedList;
}

public static MusicV3[] sortByArtist(MusicV3 [] songs){
    MusicV3[] sortedList = songs;
    int i;
    int k;
    int posmax;
    MusicV3 temp;
    for ( i = songs.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i-- )
    {
       posmax = 0;
         for ( k = 0 ; k <= i ; k++ )
         {
             if (songs[k].getArtist().compareTo(songs[posmax].getArtist()) > 0)
             posmax = k;
            }

            temp = songs[i];
            songs[i] = songs[posmax];
            songs[posmax] = temp;
        }
return sortedList;
}

public static int findSong( MusicV3[] songs, String song){
 int high = songs.length;
 int low = -1;
 int probe;

 while ( high - low > 1 )
 {
 probe = ( high + low ) / 2;
 if (songs[probe].getTitle().compareTo(song) > 0)
  high = probe;
 else 
  low = probe;
 }

 if ( low >= 0 && songs[low].getTitle().compareTo(song) == 0){
return low;
}
else{
 return -1;
}
}

public static int findYear(MusicV3[] songs, int year){
 int high = songs.length - 1;
 int low = 0;
 int probe;

 while (low <= high)
 {
 probe = ( high + low ) / 2;
 if (songs[probe].getYear() == year)
  return probe;
  if(songs[probe].getYear() > year)
  low = probe;
else 
 low = probe + 1;
} 
return -1;
}

public static void findArtist(MusicV3[] s, String artist)
{
    int found = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        if (s[i].getArtist().compareTo(artist) == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(s[i]);
            found++;
        }
    }
    if (found == 0)
    { // we have not found the location
        System.out.println("There are no songs on the songs list made in the year " + artist);
        System.out.println();
    } 
    else
    {
        System.out.print("There were " + found + " listings for " + artist);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

Ignore the song and artist search, those I can do and have no problems with but with the year search, it's not working correctly since it is supposed to correctly print all of the songs that are in the specific year giving (2000 and 2014) but it isn't and instead is not working at all and asking for an input for some reason. This is my first time doing a binary search so i'm pretty new to this.

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: Hint:  Carefully compare your code for binary search by year against your code for binary search by song title.   Do you see the difference?

Comment: Does `sortByYear()` work correctly?

Comment: Yes all the sorts work correctly

Answer (score 0):

How can you possibly show all of them when you are only returning the index of one of them (and not even the first one at that) ?

Try returning a list of results. or a `Pair<int, int>` of indexes begin and end